# Logic problem combining paging and search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that lists all the products. It's a long list so I gave the users paging ablility, and I give the user the standard page list on the bottom of the page so they can go to the next page or any page. I calculate the page based on the total number of products and the number of rows displayed on one page. No issues.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from products limit " . $page . ', ' . $rows_per_page
```

I now added search ability so the user can start the list with a product starting with a given letter, i.e. start with product starting with "s" or "sneaker".

I'm having problems combining the search and paging. How do I figure out what page within the full list, their search would end up in so I can give them the ability to go to the next page or a previous page.

Offering next page only is easy because I can start a new paging list starting with the search product:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from products WHERE product_name >= '". $search ."' limit " . $page . ', ' . $rows_per_page
```

but that will not let the user go backwards.

Comment: I'm trying to show the list, starting with the search item and the ability to go page forward or backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some information is the MySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html written in 2007 by Ian Storms, which seems to work. I don't know about the efficiency or the internal performance cos, nor  do I really understand the sql

```
set @row=-1;
select foo.Row,foo.product_name 
from (select @row:= @row+1 AS Row, product_name from products order by product_name ) 
  AS foo where foo.product_name='skyy';
```

Comment: in php I discovered that you have to break the sql into 2 parts and submit them separately. The "set @row = -1;" and then the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1) You can do it the way you suggested directly if your search form is using GET, and have a variable ($page) with the start-record on it. For example, a link to www.mydomain.com/search.php?s=$search&p=$page+10 on the "next" text. This would allow you to go to any page instantaneously via the URL, but wouldn't be smart if you have sensitive information in there. Also, you'd have to do a separate call to the server for each page.

2) You can do it the way you suggested indirectly with SESSION variables. You can store $search and $page, and have your next/previous buttons be POST form submissions. Format your MySQL query limits ahead or backwards of $page depending on the variable submitted. But again, this requires a new server request for every page.

3) You can get the entire list of results at once and use Javascript to selectively show some of them. For example, you can print the first ten results in a div with display: block and the others in other divs with display: hidden. Then your buttons can have an onclick event which shows the appropriate div of results.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There are 200,000 products so option 3 is out. Now let's say we show 200 products at a time. The problem I'm having is if they search for "sne" I don't know what page that will be in, so if they want to go back a page showing the previous 200 products, I don't know know to get there.

Comment: @sdfor Roughly speaking, you need to determine where in the ordered list of your products the first occurrence of "sne" appears - say it's at product 58176 of 200000. Now, knowing that and your `records per page`, you can determine what page that record should appear on: `58176 / 200 = 290.88`, hence you should display page 291...

Comment: yes, that I understand. That's the question. How do I determine at what record number "sne" appears.